# Laravel resources wrap twice when unit testing

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.7

When I run a test suit, my tests that return a `ResourceCollection` fails because the data is wrap twice but success when I run them individually.

**I already know the cause**
`ResourceCollection` use a **static** variable called **wrap** and between the tests, this variable keep his state.

**Now I need to fix it**

Take theses two methods as starting point in the **OrganizationsController**

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return OrganizationsResource
 */
public function index(Request $request): OrganizationsResource
{
    return new OrganizationsResource(
        Organization::paginate()
    );
}

/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Organization $organization
 * @return OrganizationResource
 */
public function show(Request $request, Organization $organization): OrganizationResource
{
    OrganizationResource::withoutWrapping();
    return new OrganizationResource($organization);
}
```

The **OrganizationsResource**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class OrganizationsResource extends ResourceCollection
{

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request): array
    {
        return [
            'data' => OrganizationResource::collection($this->collection),
        ];
    }
}
```

And the **OrganizationResource**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class OrganizationResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {

        return [
            'id'         => $this->id,
            'type'       => 'organization',
            'attributes' => [
                'name' => $this->resource->name,
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

**This works perfectly fine** the response given for the **index** will be build like this:

```
{
 "data": [
    {"id": 1},{"id": 2}, ....
 ],
 "links": {
    "next": "http://...",
    ....
 },
 "meta": {
    "current_page": 1,
    ....
 }
}
```

And as expected, the **show** will return

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "type" "organization",
    ....
}
```

**However**, when I run all my unit tests, my **index(es)** returns the the following json (notice `{"data":{"data"...`

```
{
 "data": {
     "data": [
        {"id": 1},{"id": 2}, ....
     ],
     "links": {
        "next": "http://...",
        ....
     },
     "meta": {
        "current_page": 1,
        ....
     }
    }
}
```

Here's one of the test that succeed when running alone but fail after `withoutWrapping` as been called once in a test suit

```
/** @test */
public function organizations_api_index_returns_valid_schema(): void
{
    factory(Organization::class, 2)->create(['name' => 'My-Company']);
    $this->json('get', '/organizations')->assertJsonSchema(base_path("{$this->schema}/organizations.json"));
}
```

In case you wondering about `assertJsonSchema` this is from [sixlive/laravel-json-schema-assertions](https://github.com/sixlive/laravel-json-schema-assertions)

#### Temporary workaround

I'm running my tests with `processIsolation` set to `true` in my **phpunit.xml** But it's extremely slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not satisfied with my answer, but it fix the error if I set `$wrap` manually in my ResourceCollection.

```
class OrganizationsResource extends ResourceCollection
{
    public static $wrap = 'data';

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request): array
    {
        return [
            'data' => OrganizationResource::collection($this->collection),
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this issue in 2024, maybe check if anywhere in your code you are using a `JsonResource` for a model, for example `UserResource`, and you disable wrapping using `UserResource::withoutWrapping()` for one usage, it will affect randomly all other endpoints for testing.

So if you want to not wrap for an endpoint, prefer using `return response()->json(new UserResource($user));`.